# Sitecore workbox only display the latest Version of an item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-workflow

I have customized workbox by overriding it. By default Workbox displays all versions of items in a particular workflow state.
I need only the last version to appear in the workbox.
Played around with the `DisplayStates(IWorkflow workflow, XmlControl placeholder)` method, but no luck.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override `DisplayStates()` method and filter the `DataUri[] items` array:

```cs
List<DataUri> filteredUriList = new List<DataUri>();
DataUri[] items = this.GetItems(state, workflow);

for (int index = offset; index < num; ++index)
{
    Item obj = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.Items[items[index]];
    if (obj != null && obj.Versions.IsLatestVersion())
        filteredUriList.Add(items[index]);
}
items = filteredUriList.ToArray();
```

Comment: Sitecore uses, this.GetItems(state, workflow) method to get items. In our database there are like 700,000+ sitecore items with workflow states assigned. Does Sitecore use indexing internally? I am using lucene indexing in the public website. Do you think it's bettet to use indexing inside the workbox?

Comment: +++ and also something about "DataURI", if I use indexing and return a item[], how can I convert it back to a DataUri. Is this a good approach?

Comment: I don't know if Sitecore uses indexing for getting the list of items in particular workflow state. You can use constructor `new DataUri(item.ID, item.Language, item.Version)` to create `DataUri` from `Item`.